# Performance of one-way bound interpolation versus ng-bind in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, interpolation

We know that ng-bind is more performant than two-way- bound interpolation {{ vm.variables }}.

But is ng-bind more performant that one-way- bound interpolated variables {{ ::vm.variables }} ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide/issues/41#issuecomment-159970599) discussion **ng-bind** is **faster** than **expression bind** and **one-time bind** at the **first load**, because interpolation has to go through extra steps of verifying context, jsonification of values and more. But **one-time bind** is **more performant**.

I'd recommend using **ng-bind** instead of **expression bind** and **one-time bind** if the expression will not be recalculated.